# In AutoHotKey, how to use mouse to select text in the background?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a legacy text based database whose data cannot be exported. I have to use mouse to select data on screen, and do ctrl+c to copy them to a txt file. I have managed to do this using AutoHotKey. Now I want this to be run in the background without interfering my other job on the computer.

The database will be an inactive hidden window. I could use ControlClick and ControlSend to type things. But I cannot select a piece of text like the way I do when the window is active. I tried the following but it does not work:

```
ControlClick, X%dat_x1% Y%dat_y1%, ahk_id %database_window_id%,,,,NA D
ControlClick, X%dat_x2% Y%dat_y2%, ahk_id %database_window_id%,,,,NA U
```

I guess it's because the mouse isn't moved using ControlClick. Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe WinGetText can help?

Answer (score 1):

"I guess it's because the mouse isn't moved using ControlClick."

If WinGetText (or `Send, ^a^c` to select all and copy) and then some regex pattern can't be used, maybe, after the click, you could just use `Send, +{Right}` to select..? Or for example `Send, ^+{Right 7}` to select 7 whole words/spaces.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But for now I won't bother to run it on background. I will just run it on a spare laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the database itself if you had the right permissions.

I've used this in the past:  https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/90862-acclib-access-database/